# Why do I receive an error stating coercing to unicode in Python?

Tags: python, error-handling, opencsv

I am trying to write a code that will fetch an api from my csv as input:

```
from pyzillow.pyzillow import ZillowWrapper, GetDeepSearchResults, GetUpdatedPropertyDetails

def get_zillowinfo(address,zipcode):
    zillow_data = ZillowWrapper('X1-ZWz17seirkzuh7_93aho')
    deep_search_response = zillow_data.get_deep_search_results(address,zipcode)
    result1 = GetDeepSearchResults(deep_search_response) #get zillowid from address
    updated_property_details_response = zillow_data.get_updated_property_details(result1.zillow_id)
    result2 = GetUpdatedPropertyDetails(updated_property_details_response) # get detail property info
    result = result2.home_info
    return result

print get_zillowinfo('73 main blvd','01545')

#2
import csv
with open(r'C:\Users\bca\Desktop\Pricing Study-Zillow\sample4.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    next(spamreader)
    for row in spamreader:
        print row


#3
import csv
with open(r'C:\Users\bca\Desktop\Pricing Study-Zillow\sample4.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    next(spamreader)
    for row in spamreader:
            print get_zillowinfo(row[0],row[1])
```

When i do step #3, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\bca\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2895, in run_code
    self.showtraceback()

  File "C:\Users\bca\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1828, in showtraceback
    self._showtraceback(etype, value, stb)

  File "C:\Users\bca\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 547, in _showtraceback
    u'evalue' : py3compat.safe_unicode(evalue),

  File "C:\Users\bca\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipython_genutils\py3compat.py", line 65, in safe_unicode
    return unicode_type(e)

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, dict found
```

Why does this happen? is it because my characters are not strings? how do I change it to string in that case for all my data?

This is a repex of my dataset:
[image]

What do I need to change in my code to avoid that type error?

Comment: Show us the full error traceback.

Comment: @JohnGordon ive reedited with full traceback

Comment: It might help to see the (non-IPython) traceback that IPython is failing to display.